# TYPO3 - Printing view of page has weird information

Tags: typo3

When I try to print a page from my site created in TYPO3, I can read at the end of every link the string "(index.php?id=2) and or the ID of the page where the link goes.

How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using an extension like [realurl](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/realurl) or [cooluri](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cooluri) (I recommend the first). This will not only look better on your print view, but will also have positive effect on SEO.

UPDATE: Ok, I think I understood you wrong in the first place. I guess you mean you have the url appended to EVERY link on the website, not just in the header/footer of the printed page, right? Do you use a css framework like YAML? Some of them contain code like

```
a[href]:after {
     content: " ("attr(href)")";
}
```

in their print stylesheets, which adds the url of each link at the end of the link. Search for that part and remove it. You may also enable print preview in Firebug or whatever browser you use to develop. Then you should see the same result and also the css which is responsible for this behavior.

Comment: You were totally right. That was in the normalize.css file! Amazing! I cant imagine why would someone put that in the first place :P Thanks!